# Auto-Scroll while dragging an item with Perfect-Scrollbar and SortableJs

Tags: scroll, drag-and-drop, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar, sortablejs

Is it possible to make [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar) automatically scroll up/down while dragging an item in the edge its container? In this case for the drag & drop, I'm using [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable).

To reproduce my use case try to drag the Item 1 to the end of the list (after Item 8): https://jsfiddle.net/hfalucas/fwzcse9k/5/

In the first list, you can not drag the item, because the scroll doesn't move at all

```
// js file
var ps = new PerfectScrollbar('.container');


Sortable.create(list, {
  animation: 150,
});


// httml
<div id="coisas" class="container">
  <div id="list" class="list-group content">
      <div class="list-group-item">1</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">2</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">3</div>
      (...)
  </div>
</div>
```

In the second list and using the browser native scroll it works perfectly

```
Sortable.create(listOne, {
    animation: 150,
});


// httml
<div id="cenas" class="container">
  <div id="listOne" class="list-group content">
      <div class="list-group-item">1</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">2</div>
      <div class="list-group-item">3</div>
      (...)
  </div>
</div>

//css
#cenas {
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 206px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Changed from using perferct-scrollbar to simplebar(vue-simplebar)

Comment: @Heldar Lucas, can you please post the solution if found.

Comment: @Manzer as said in the previous comment, I ended up changing plugin, haven't found any solution :(